# Where can I manage GitHub's tokens for VSCode?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-api, vscode-remote

I connected to github from vscode. From what I saw, it generated a OAuth2 token with vscode-auth.github.com

Now, I would like to know:

1. How I can disable this token from github.com (it doesn't show up in https://github.com/settings/developers)
2. How I can delete this token from my VSCode installation
3. How it works on remote sessions: it looks like magic but I would also need to clean the keys from my remote server

Answer (score 1):

The applications which are authorized by `OAuth` are listed at https://github.com/settings/applications and under tab `Authorized OAuth Apps` and from there one can revoke the authorization.

[image]